# Image follow the mouse, using mousemove event (using Jquery/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousemove

I want the image to follow along with the mouse when the mouse is move but when the mouse has clicked once anywhere the image stops following; it begins following when the mouse has clicked again

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Mousemove">
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).click(function(e) {
     $(".image").mousemove({ top: e.pageY, left: e.pageX });
      });
      
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
    <img class="image" src="../images/food%20photgraphy2.jpg" height="50px" width="55px" alt="food">
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, when the mouse moves the image doesn't follow along with the mouse and I'm not able to click anywhere. Why is my code not working?

Comment: you want to move image when click by mouse. then if click again movement of image will stop ? right

Comment: Maybe you need set image's position to absolute position, then you can control image's movement

Comment: @palaѕн okay, I just added to my post

Comment: So I want the image to follow along with the mouse when the mouse is move but when the mouse has clicked once anywhere the image stops following; it begins following when the mouse has clicked again @aviboy2006

Answer (score 2):

Simply as you can see in this snippet, I add a class once the document clicked and and based on that we change the element position, [bind/unbind](https://api.jquery.com/unbind/) `mousemove` event and also remove the added class or not based on alternated click, I think this is what you want:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(this).click(function (e) {
    if ($('body').hasClass("clicked")) {
      $('body').removeClass("clicked");
      $("img").css({ top: 0, left: 0 });
      $(this).unbind('mousemove');

    } else {
      $('body').addClass("clicked");
      $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
        $("img").css({ top: e.pageY, left: e.pageX });
      });      
    }
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  position:absolute
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/30x30">
```

Updated snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
    if (!$('body').hasClass("clicked")) {
      $("img").css({ top: e.pageY, left: e.pageX });          
    }
  });  



  $(this).click(function (e) {
    if ($('body').hasClass("clicked")) {
      $('body').removeClass("clicked");
      //$("img").css({ top: 0, left: 0 });
      //$(this).unbind('mousemove');

    } else {
      $('body').addClass("clicked");
      //$(this).mousemove(function (e) {
        //$("img").css({ top: e.pageY, left: e.pageX });
      //});      
    }
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/30x30">
```

Comment: you must provide [position css attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) to make it work  you can use `relative` position value if you want.

Comment: Thank you Root. What if I want the image to following along with the mouse before the click. then when is click the image stop following, then it begins following when the mouse has clicked again? (hope it makes sense)

Comment: @b2700,  we can specify another attribute `translate` to change the image location instead of left/top position, and for the other thing, can you edit the question and point what the functionality should be? that would make it clear instead of having it here in the comments.

Comment: @b2700 I added another snippet, check it out.

Comment: Thank you!! quick question, so in this case you will not be able  to use mousemove then ? Can you use mousemove in order to control ?

Comment: You can use mouse move normally but if you mean click events,  it will be prevented since the image preventing other elements click event from being fired.  please consider [accepting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and upvote if you find my answer useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Click toggle between events, nest the mousemove in one instance along with addClass('image') and then removeClass('image') in the other.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.clickToggle = function(func1, func2) {
    var funcs = [func1, func2];
    this.data('toggleclicked', 0);
    this.click(function() {
      var data = $(this).data();
      var tc = data.toggleclicked;
      $.proxy(funcs[tc], this)();
      data.toggleclicked = (tc + 1) % 2;
    });
    return this;
  };
}(jQuery));

$('#move').clickToggle(function() {
  $(this).mousemove(function(e) {
    $('.image').css({
      'top': e.clientY - 20,
      'left': e.clientX - 20
    });    
  });
  $('#img').addClass('image');
}, function() {
  $('.image').removeClass("image");
});
```

```css
#img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body id="move">
  <img class="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQXNfNpnfElPqK1QE2BSbDlBd49DQZE-xlNxRlLKQxIscKgIKpP&usqp=CAU" height="50px" width="55px" alt="food" id="img">
  <div id="log"></div>
</body>
```